# how to plot using ggplot with different colors and ordered in decreasing order with

Tags: r, ggplot2

For some dataset I have the following table (top row is NLE, bottom is counts)

```
 Table of 'Data':
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 22 
 7  6 18 14 36 66 80 54 39 23 12  7  1  1  1
```

I am using following barplot functions.

```
# Top 10
with(file1, barplot(rev(sort(table(NLE))[1:10]), xlab='No. of L', ylab='Counts', main = 'Top LEve'))

# Bar plot of all in ascending order
barplot( sort( table(file1$NLE), decreasing=TRUE), xlab='No. of L', ylab='Counts', main = 'LEve Per CWC')
```

Can someone help me to draw the same in ggplot using different colors in bars and dotted lines from the mid of the bar to the Y-axis.

Comment: Can you please provide a reproducible example? Also please show the output of the above barplots

Comment: There is a nice [documented example](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_bar.html) of how to create an "identity" barplot. Adding color is just a small detail of specifying the correct aesthetic. What have you tried that doesn't work?

Comment: actually guys it is simple to work on. If someone is smart enough, one could have done the way I am doing below. Just as the start...

Comment: Simplicity was the point of Roman's comment. It probably should have been marked as a duplicate. My downvote was for lack of effort. A google search with "ggplot2 equivalent of bar plot" brings up a wealth of items.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your data table has this..

```
Table   Count
1   7
2   6
3   18
4   14
5   36
6   66
7   80
8   54
9   39
10  23
11  12
12  7
13  1
14  1
22  1
```

What I did, simply copied the above data in clipboard and used below r code to do the rest... I also asusme that you have ggplot2 insalled on your system.

```
# reading from clipboard
dat <- read.delim("clipboard")
# ggplot
ggplot(dat, aes(y=dat$Count, x = dat$Table)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

Comment: I would suggest not using `$` inside the `aes()`

Comment: The attempted edit changed `geom_bar` to `geom_col` which I thought changed the original contribution, although it did simplify the code. Agreed that the `dat$` instances should be removed.